# Git: send parameters to 'post-receive' hook with the 'git push' command

Tags: git, deployment, hook, githooks, git-push

I have configured a `post-receive` hook script on a server for automatic deploy with Git, as described for example [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps).

So, when on my local PC I send a push on the production server:

```
git push production master
```

the `post-receive` hook is triggered, copying the content of the repository inside the live directory.

My question is if is there some way to pass some parameter to the `post-receive` hook when I send the push?

Something like this:

```
git push production master --params="clear-the-cache=1"
```

then within the hook I can read the `'clear-the-cache=1'` parameter and perform additional operations.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: A `post-receive` hook itself takes no arguments. Maybe you could read `clear-the-cache=1` from some config file, which you have added into the repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I send out of band data along with a commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787125/can-i-send-out-of-band-data-along-with-a-commit)

Answer (score 7):

**Edit: Git version 2.10.0** added a new `--push-option` (aka `-o`) argument to `git push`, which provides a nice clean way to do this.  [Thanks to Steve Coffman for reminding me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360442/git-send-parameters-to-post-receive-hook-with-the-git-push-command/37360794?noredirect=1#comment70900715_37360794)  Both server and client need to be at 2.10.0 or higher; the supplied options, one per `-o` or `--push-option` argument, are then passed to both the pre-receive and post-receive hooks as arguments.

---

Not cleanly.  There are some methods by which you could provide a side channel, but I think they are all quite ugly.

Consider that every `git push` pushes one or more reference labels.  If you push at least two labels every time, one of the labels can point to objects (commits, tags, etc) that carry additional information.  The form of that additional information is up to you.

Git generally will not allow you to push arbitrary ref-space names like `refs/sidechannel`:

```
remote: error: refusing to create funny ref 'refs/sidechannel' remotely
 ! [remote rejected] refs/sidechannel -> refs/sidechannel (funny refname)
```

(though I accidentally discovered that github thinks this means to create a *branch* named `refs/sidechannel`.  Odd.)  Anyway, this means that in general, you would have to use a branch or tag name.  For instance:

```
git push production master sidechannel
```

In your post-receive script, you could then check for updates to `refs/heads/sidechannel` and do whatever you like with them (including extract information, then delete the branch).

Alternatively, you could use ordinary annotated tags or specially formatted text in commit messages to provide side-channel data.  Or, since `refs/notes` is now a recognized name space, use `refs/notes/name` as the name of the side channel.

Comment: It seems quite complex for me setting up this, but I will try your solutions. Thank you.

Comment: You might consider [ElpieKay's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360442/git-send-parameters-to-post-receive-hook-with-the-git-push-command/37360794?noredirect=1#comment62235821_37360442), which is likely simpler.  A file named `.params` would be hidden from normal view, for instance.  I'm not sure there are any *good* solutions here; these are all bad solutions with different tradeoffs. :-)

Comment: If you are on git 2.10 or newer version, you may find [git push-option](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41839473/2904179) helpful