# the receiving end does not support push options

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

At first my server's git version was 2.7.4 and the error was accurate. Afterwards, however, I updated and have confirmed this with git version:

Server

```
$ git --version  
git version 2.13.0
```

Client

```
$ git --version  
git version 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)
```

Yet when I try to push this happens:

```
$ git push --push-option=test  
fatal: the receiving end does not support push options  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Even though according to documentation this should be supported in both the client version and server version:
[2.11.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/2.11.0#git-push--o)
[2.13.0](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push/2.13.0#git-push--o)

I even created two new local repositories on each and then tried to push to the other local repository from the other (so it isn't even communicating between a different server) yet I still get that error. Is there something I have to enable? I can't find anything about having to do that on the docs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After searching through code until I found the actual [tests](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/t/t5545-push-options.sh) for push options I found out you have to enable a specific config for the repository which is *conveniently* disabled by default: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-receiveadvertisePushOptions

You can enable it, in the **server side**, with

```
$ git config receive.advertisePushOptions true
```

This is also conveniently not referenced anywhere on the actual documentation for `git push` or even, as far as I can tell, anywhere else at all.

Comment: Thanks for digging in to this! Sounds like the documentation needs updated.

Comment: Updated deeplink: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-receiveadvertisePushOptions

Answer (score -1):

Just do not use push options.

No:

```
git push -o ci.skip
```

Yes:

```
git push
```